# postgresql: non-table expression in from-list?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a table

```
id | description
-----------------
1  |  aaa        
2  |  bbb
```

I accidentally wrote

```
select * from the_table, upper(description)
```

and was very surprised to get the result

```
id | description | upper
-------------------------
1  |  aaa        | AAA
2  |  bbb        | BBB
```

How/why does this work? The documentation mentions that comma-separated entries in the from-clause must be table-like structures, which are then cross-join together. Here neither is true. Which part of the syntax & semantics allows this??

Answer (score 2):

This is tacitly handled like this:

```
select *
from the_table
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL upper(description) AS upper;
```

The reason:

- having several `FROM` list entries amounts to a cross join, see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM):

  > If more than one table reference is listed in the `FROM` clause, the tables are cross-joined (that is, the Cartesian product of their rows is formed).
- a function call in the `FROM` list is treated as if there were `LATERAL`, as the documentation says:

  > Table functions appearing in `FROM` can also be preceded by the key word `LATERAL`, but for functions the key word is optional

The missing puzzle piece here is that `upper` is no table function. That is true, but PostgreSQL is a bit fuzzy about this: any function can be used as a table function (so you can run `SELECT * FROM sin(pi() / 2);`), and in many contexts you can use table functions outside the `FROM` clause (like in `SELECT generate_series(1, 10);`).

The former is not documented, [but the latter is](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-SET), although it is not easy to find.

Comment: But `upper()` is not a "table function"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You are right. I added something about that.

Comment: point is, if `upper(..)` was treated like a table, shouldn't `from` produce the cartesian product of the two tables??

Comment: Yes, it does produce a Cartesian product (that's whet a `CROSS JOIN` is). But `upper(...)` returns only a single row, so the result has just as many lines as `the_table`.

Answer (score 1):

Once, I had a similar question:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/241369/understanding-joined-set-returning-functions-in-the-from-list

There I was joining a [set-returning function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html). This automatically makes the `CROSS JOIN` to a `CROSS JOIN LATERAL`.

So, it seems, that you created a `LATERAL` join, as well, which would explain the result.

The accepted answer from the my question explain that behaviour quite well:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/241372/161799

Comment: but this is not a set-returning function. It takes a string and returns a string

Comment: that is true for *every* sql function though. functions are considered set-returning if they may return *more than one* rows

Comment: @S-Man: the function is marked as returning 0 rows and `proretset` is set to false. So it's not marked as a set-returning function

Comment: Hm, ok, thanks :) But it is using the LATERAL nonetheless, or am I wrong?